# Should fence post height be adjusted to accommodate panel height when on a slope?

Tags: fence

We are building a vinyl fence on a slight slope and want to know how to handle the difference in post / fence heights.

The next fence post is sunk 24" is an inch shorter than the first. Do we adjust the brackets higher to make the panel level or adjust the fence post?  We can't do a step down because it is the same panel.

Comment: I don't understand "it is the same panel".

Comment: Yes prefab panels.  Thank you!

Comment: That  doesn't explain why you can't do a step down.

Answer (score 2):

When building a fence you need to decide which strategy you'll go with when it comes to slopes:

1. Skew the panels into parallelograms so they follow the slope ("racking" in this image)
2. Step the panels down to ground level at the high point for each segment

[image]
<sub>[source](https://www.lowes.com/n/buying-guide/fence-buying-guide)</sub>

In either case, **post height depends on the height of the panel top *at the low end***. You want the same extension above the higher panel for each post.

My $.02: I find the step-down approach comically goofy-looking for anything more than a mild slope. They end up looking like sails in the wind and quite inelegant. The steps look wrong and the gaps under the low ends can be very large, reducing the intended benefit of having a fence. I'd skew the panels if possible. A smooth line along the top is much nicer.

Comment: I think that they are using pre-fab panels so the racking condition isn't an option. What to do in that case, is I think at the heart of their question

Comment: Some pre-fab panels can be racked a bit (especially vinyl), and if I haven't addressed the question with the stepping option I apparently don't understand the question.

Comment: They stated that they can't do the stepping option: "We can't do a step down because it is the same panel." They are probably also using prefab posts. Actually I doubt either of us get what they are asking because I think that they are also not clear on that...